# I can't install npm not matter what I do

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

So I'm trying to get myself a good Discord Selfbot and one of them requires nodejs, then it said to do npm install. But it gave me an error. I tried again again again and again but nothing worked. The latest thing I did was installing nodejs via scoop but I get this error trying to install npm. Is there a way to do this manually or something? I've tried installing different versions but nothing. I believe scoop installed the latest version.
[Here's the image. (the red squares cover up just names)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB21Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have npm already installed, seems that the problem is you don't have a package.json in that location. It says `ENOENT: No such file or directory`

Comment: How do I fix this then?

Comment: You need a package.json file in the current directory you are located. If you don't have that file you can create it, just type in `npm init` and it will guide you trough the creation

Comment: Oh wait, it seems the folder has an package.json. Now how could I run the .js file? (How you run the bot is through an .js file.)

Comment: If the folder has a `package.json` then maybe you are not placed in the right directory in the terminal. Look at the path where you are and make sure it is right. Also look at the `package.json` file to see if it is well-formed.

Comment: Okay nvm I got it. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You already have npm installed! npm is a package manager for installing nodejs packages.  Try running some nonsense command (like "lkajshdflhsf") and you'll see what it looks like if you actually didn't have npm installed.  What `npm install` does is install some package.  So, for example, if you want to install a node package called Blah, you would run `npm intall blah`.